Using MSAL-REACT and MSAL-BROWSER In React-Capacitor
I have a basic React application integrated with Capacitor, and I want the user to login with Keycloak when clicking the button. The login is working fine, but what I need is it should redirect back to the application after redirection, but I'm currently redirected back to localhost:
import { Configuration } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import * as msal from "@azure/msal-browser";

// Config object to be passed to Msal on creation
export const MsalInstance: Configuration = {
  auth: {
    protocolMode: msal.ProtocolMode.OIDC,
    authorityMetadata: JSON.stringify({
      authorization_endpoint: `https://${import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOCK_BASE_URL}/realms/${import.meta.env.VITE_REALM_DEV}/protocol/openid-connect/auth`,
      token_endpoint: `https://${import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOCK_BASE_URL}/realms/${import.meta.env.VITE_REALM_DEV}/protocol/openid-connect/token`,
      issuer: `https://${import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOCK_BASE_URL}/realms/${import.meta.env.VITE_REALM_DEV}`,
      userinfo_endpoint: `https://${import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOCK_BASE_URL}/realms/${import.meta.env.VITE_REALM_DEV}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo`,
    }),
    authority: `https://${import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOCK_BASE_URL}/realms/${import.meta.env.VITE_REALM_DEV}`,
    clientId: `${import.meta.env.VITE_CLIENT_ID_DEV}`,
    knownAuthorities: [`https://${import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOCK_BASE_URL}/realms/${import.meta.env.VITE_REALM_DEV}`],
  },
};

Here is how I am using it:
const mInstance = new PublicClientApplication(MsalInstance);
await mInstance.initialize();
const authenticationResult = await msalInstance?.loginPopup();

I have already tested with redirectURI in the MsalInstance.

I resolved it using https://github.com/moberwasserlechner/capacitor-oauth2
